# Passing data frame data through function

Tags: r, function, difference, least-squares

```
# mtcars <- view(mtcars)

sq_sum_diff <- function(d, w) {  # d, and c are columns draft and weight
  a <- d^2
  b <- w^2
  p <- sqrt(sum(a^2 - b^2)
  return(p)
}
```

What I want returned is a df with the difference in squares between the two.

Comment: `d <- data.frame( d=with( mtcars, sq_sum_diff( draft, weight) ))`. And do test your code in the future before displaying your efforts to the world on StackOverflow. You have a missing parenthesis. (Maybe you meant `drat`?)

Comment: You don't need to use `return()`  when you are just returning the last line.  Are you saying you want to return a single column data frame with   a^2-b^2  (i.e d^4 - w^4)?  Or do you want to add a new column to the existing data frame?

Comment: @IRTFM,Sorry for the typo. Looking back it was a copy and paste issue. Sorry.

Comment: @Elin, yes, you are correct in your 1st question. I think if I wanted to do that, however, I need to remove the `sum` function right? Also, thank you for the correction about the 'return()'. I am still new to coding, so any correction helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you're trying to accomplish:

```
data(mtcars)

sq_sum_diff <- function(d, w) {
  sqrt(sum(d^2 - w^2))
}
sq_sum_diff(mtcars$drat, mtcars$wt)


library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  summarize(dif_sqr = sq_sum_diff(drat, wt))
```

Why are you squaring the values twice? Once when you assign `d^2` to `a` and again when you calculate the sum of squares? Also, you're missing the matching parenthesis of `sqrt`. Lastly, you don't need to assign to `p` and then `return(p)`, the function will automatically return the last line. And for future reference, you can simply call `data(mtcars)` without assigning it to `mtcars`.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response! I figured that part out already. Since I have posted this, I have removed the `sum` function, ran the code, and got a 31 rows of data. I think I can turn that into a `df`.

Comment: I missed the part about wanting a data.frame. I added a bit of code to my answer that would produce a data frame with a single column for difference of squares if that's helpful.